# Link with target="_blank" still affected by pseudo-class :hover styles after user clicked on it, Chrome only

Tags: css, google-chrome

After a user clicks to link with target="_blank" link opens the second tab, then the user decides to get back to the previous page (to the first tab) where the user came from with current link.

Till moment user will not drag the cursor to document (page) itself, `:hover` styling effects still will be there.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/verhc6f1) is simple code example:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper:hover .tooltip {
  transition: 'opacity 0.5s step-end';
  opacity: 1;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
  <div class="tooltip">
    Tooltip
  </div>
</div>
```

And actually code can be even easier, I just described my case above, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/47r1uz2d/) is a more basic example:

```css
a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

That's happening only in Chrome (84.0.4147.125). To make it easier for you to understand the problem, I made [screen-recording](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rnxuzwnez964p7u/Screen%20Recording%202020-08-14%20at%2016.05.41.mov?dl=0). Also might happen only in macOS, didn't check on Windows/Linux.

Is it possible somehow to fix it and make it work as other browsers do? After switching tabs, `:hover` effects are disappearing immediately without waiting till user bring the cursor to page.

Comment: I am using Chrome 84.0.4147.125 and it just doesn't happen for me in neither of your examples (good you posted the screen recording so I can be sure what bug is supposed to happen and no, it doesn't). Maybe you have a plugin causing this?

Comment: Hey @alotropico, thanks for your interest! Just checked in private mode, still happens for me. Are you using Windows/Linux? I'm using macOS, maybe that's why. I'll add this info to question now.

Comment: I'm on Windows, I guees it is a macOS problem but we'll see

Comment: As it's macOS bug, I think it make sence now to create Chrome bug.

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour on macOS on Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out, how to "fix" this. Please check firstly [@johannchopin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8583669/johannchopin) answer before reading this answer, as my fix related to situations when developer trying to control child elements on hover.

So, my [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/7aLes41g/) will be:

```js
const onMouseEnter = () => {
    document.querySelector('a').blur()
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
  if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
    document.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      onMouseEnter()
      document.removeEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseEnter)
    })
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper:hover:not(:focus-within) .tooltip {
  transition: opacity 0.5s step-end;
  opacity: 1;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="wrapper">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
  <div class="tooltip">
    Tooltip
  </div>
</span>
```

Let me explain a bit about what I did here. After I read [@johannchopin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8583669/johannchopin) answer, I found out that `:focus` works only for the current element. After googling a bit, I found that there's :[focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) pseudo-class to work with current AND with nested elements. Then I added selector like `.wrapper:hover:not(:focus-within) .tooltip` to hide with `opacity` my tooltip when user focusing (most of the time it's anyway a click in my case).

But I stacked with another problem, the tooltip wasn't visible on hover after I tried to perform the same after I clicked link once before. So, I added a bit of JavaScript which I think it's pretty clear what it does. Seems there's no pure CSS solutions for issue in general.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround would be to use the `:not(:focus)` selector on your anchor:

```css
a:hover:not(:focus) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

Check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9q0wzuhj/2/) to see the working example.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer, you basically gave me an idea of how to resolve the issue in my case, with nested elements. I rewarded you with the bounty for giving me a general idea and marked my answer as the real answer. I think it's honest. Please check my answer for the solution with children inside of the focused element. Thanks and have a nice day :)